# How can I restrict which client machines can connect to Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs

I am planning to move Team Foundation Server (TFS 2012) from within premises to the Cloud. So essentially this means the URL of the TFS is now an internet facing URL instead of being a network facing URL earlier. e.g. earlier it was http://mynetworkserver:8080/tfs. Now it is https://example.com/tfs. The TFS server was/is not part of any Active Directory.  Up-till now only machines within the network could have access to the code. My main concern now is security of the code. Anyone who has a valid username/password can pull the code to their machine from the Internet. Is there any mechanism available in TFS to restrict/specify which client machines are allowed to pull code from TFS ? This must be a universal concern when moving to the cloud ? How is this addressed ?

If that is not possible, is there any way to trigger notification emails when someone has pulled the code along with the IP address or any other identifier from where the code was pulled ?

PS: Note that currently I am not considering moving to Azure Dev-Ops.

Comment: You can use the networking capabilities in Azure to create a VPN tunnel into your on-prem network and isolate your TFS server from the public internet. Do that. Start by reading the documentation on Azure networking and go from there; the subject is far too big to give any specific advice. Also, use Active Directory.

Comment: I agree this might be a broad question but one needs to ask question to get a starting point. For researching any topic, you at-least need to know where to start looking for.. Thanks for the pointers though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want  restrict TFS access to certain IP only, like a white-list.

The simplest solution should be **editing  the allowed and blocked IP address** from the TFS website in IIS.

In IIS Manager, after selecting the site, under the IIS Area I select
 "IP Address and Domain Restrictions".

More details take a look at answer in this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/874366/block-access-to-tfs-during-update).